# How do I filterBy a range of numbers in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a catalog of a large number of rather basic products and I need to be able to filter the data using a range of numbers rather than an exact match.

I'm looping through my data like this:

```
<input type=text" v-model="nameFilter">

<div v-for"product in products | filterBy nameFilter in 'name'>
    <p>Name: {{product.name}}</p>
    <p>Width: {{product.width}}</p>
    <p>Height: {{product.height}}</p>
</div>
```

The existing `filterBy` works great. No issues there. However, I also need to filter out products based on height and width but not by exact value. I can get it to work if I filter by an exact value (eg, 0.750) but if possible I need to filter products based on a range.

For example, let's say we have this:

```
<select v-model="widthFilter">
    <option value="" selected>Filter by Width</option>
    <option value="0.000-0.999">0.000-0.999</option>
    <option value="1.000-1.999">1.000-1.999</option>
    <option value="2.000-2.999">2.000-2.999</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Obviously this would not work as-is, but is there a way to filter items given a range of numbers like this in vue.js?

Comment: Maybe `filterBy width > 'min' | filterBy width < 'max'`?

Comment: Never filter `v-for`, it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Custom-filter is helpful.

```js
Vue.filter('range', function(width, range) {
 const widthInRange = [];
 for(let i of width) {
  if(i >= range[0] && i <= range[1]) widthInRange.push(i)
 }
 return widthInRange;
});
var data = {"width": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]};
new Vue({
 el: "#obj",
 data: data
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="obj">
 <span v-for="item in width|range [2,5]">{{item}}</span>
</div>
```